# File I/O not appending

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program using File I/O but I'm having a problem where the File isn't appending. I don't have any errors, everything works good but the File isn't appending.

```
fp = fopen("file.txt", "a");

rewind(fp);

if(fp == NULL){

   fprintf(stderr, "File cant be opened\n");

    return 0;

}else{

    getString(value);

    printf("File appended!");

    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: Where's the code that would append to the file? Why are you rewinding if you want to append?

Comment: Are you writing anything to the file?

Comment: getString(value) is a method which calls a method to add into a list so let's say I input hello then hello is added to a list which I' assuming that it will append also inside the file? Correct me if I'm wrong since I'm new to C..

Comment: So, in this case, I need to do, fprintf(fp, "%s", value)?

Comment: @DontStopLearn if you want to append you need to include the code for appending, not only calling the file. In that case, fprinf will work.

Comment: And remove the `rewind` if you really want to append.

Comment: @kaylum thanks, but what if I need to append more than once?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append to a file, you need to write in it. In your example you are not.

```
FILE *file = NULL;
file = fopen(fileName, "a"); // "a" for "append"


fprintf(file, "This string is appended to the file");
fprintf(file, "This string is appended to the file"); // You can call it multiple times
fclose(file);
```

In your case:

```
fp = fopen("file.txt", "a");


if(fp == NULL){

   fprintf(stderr, "File cant be opened\n");
   return 0;
} else {
   fprintf(fp, "%s\n", value);
   fclose(fp);
}
```